# The Laplacian in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates, nonlinear-system

I am currently trying to solve the non-linear Schrodinger equation(NLSE) in cylindrical coordinates, given by 
$i\hbar\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}=-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m}\nabla^{2}\psi+g|\psi|^{2}\psi$, where $g$ is a constant.

When I write the laplacian in cylindrical coordinates and split $\psi$ as $\psi=f(r,t)e^{is\theta}\lambda(z)$, the NLSE gets converted to
$i\hbar\lambda(z)\frac{\partial f(r,t)}{\partial t}=-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m}\Big(\lambda(z)\frac{\partial^{2}f(r,t)}{\partial r^{2}}+\lambda(z)\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f(r,t)}{\partial r}-\frac{s^{2}\lambda(z)f(r,t)}{r^{2}}+f(r,t)\frac{\partial^{2}\lambda(z)}{\partial z^{2}}\Big)+g\;f^{3}(r,t)\lambda^{3}(z)$.

My question is regarding the right hand side of the above equation. Now that I have a $\theta$ independence in the equation above, can I just replace $r\rightarrow x$ in the above equation to get the $x-z$ profile, given by $\lambda(z)f(x,y=0,t)$? If yes, why? If not, why not?

Comment: You have right now the profile!! It holds for every point with $x^2+y^2$ constant, so is, $r$ constant. You can solve it substituting $r$ by $x$, but I don't get the point of doing so.

Comment: I actually am trying to solve the given equation numerically. In the Cartesian case, a Fourier transform helps simplify the derivative terms. However, a Fourier transform won't help here to simplify the derivative term over here and hence was wondering how to get the derivative terms simplified. Or else, find an algorithm which doesn't employ Fourier transforms.